# lazy loading with flex slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slider, lazy-loading

Does any one know how I can implement lazy loading to work with multiple flex slider galleries and images?

I have been trying for the last 1hr 1/2 and it's just not working.

you can see what I mean here: http://www.yetidesign.com.au/main.php

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? I really need to get this sorted out

Comment: Did you find out the answer? I am also having the same problem

Comment: No I never did, I went down another path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360533/lazy-loading-in-flexslider