# Lazy Loading in Flexslider

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lazy-loading, flexslider

I am trying to get lazy loading working for [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) by using Lazy Loading jquery plugin and following the instructions on this site: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

I am loading the plugin script and don't see any errors on console. I tried without the container or options being passed in lazyload function and still nothing. I spend hours on this.

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
  effect: "fadeIn",
  container: $(".slides > li")
});
```

Does anyone know how to get lazy loading working in Flexslider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I added the real image page to the data-attr attribute on the image tag and on `after` event fire I would find the image with `active` class and set the img src attribute equal to data-attr value.

Comment: Do you have an example? Or could you throw one up in js fiddle?

Comment: As @J0NNYZER0 says, could you put a jsfiddle up of your solution? Thx.

Answer (score 15):

**I implemented a lazy load during scrolling. This solution works better for big collections in comparison with other solutions proposed here.**  During initialization it loads only first 5 images and then it loads ahead 3 images for every animation.

```
<li>
  <img class="lazy" src="loading-image.jpg" data-src="actual-image.jpg" />
</li>
```

and javascript code:

```
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: false,
        controlNav: false,
        init: function (slider) {
            // lazy load
            $("img.lazy").slice(0,5).each(function () {
                var src = $(this).attr("data-src");
                $(this).attr("src", src).removeAttr("data-src").removeClass("lazy");
            });
        },
        before: function (slider) {
            // lazy load
            $("img.lazy").slice(0,3).each(function () {
                var src = $(this).attr("data-src");
                $(this).attr("src", src).removeAttr("data-src").removeClass("lazy");
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you send a JSFiddle or a Codepen for this bro?

Comment: @RomanPodlinov how can i use this concept to ResponsiveSlider ??

Comment: @Vikram sorry, I didn't work with ResponsiveSlider, but IMO the concept must work too. You just have to bind lazyload on the events from the slider

Comment: Still using flexslider in 2020. Great answer, simple concept, works as intended. I think this should be the accepted answer. The accepted answer hints at the same concept, but this answer is complete.

Answer (score 8):

The method works pretty well for me, but the loading image does need to be the same size as the rest of the images. I actually use http://imageresizing.net/ with mode=pad

In the main container that you are using for flexslider, put the actual image in a "data-src" attribute

```
<li>
  <img class="lazy" src="loading-image.jpg" data-src="actual-image.jpg" />
</li>
```

In you initialization function, use the "start" callback to replace the loading image with the actual image, and remove the attribute

```
$('#slider').flexslider({
    start: function (slider) {
       // lazy load
       $(slider).find("img.lazy").each(function () {
          var src = $(this).attr("data-src");
          $(this).attr("src", src).removeAttr("data-src");
       });
     }
});
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: It works for me, I make only one improvement instead of adding class="lazy" directly, I search for img with attribute "data-src"  $(slider).find("img[data-src]").each(function () ...

Comment: This helped me most noble sire. I'm much indebted to ye

Answer (score 4):

I am trying to do the same thing using [Flexslider 2](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/,) and the [Lazy Load Plugin for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload,).

It seems the `container` property only works if the element is styled with `overflow:scroll;`

I was able to get the lazy load to work using this code:

```
$("#flexcontainer img.lazy").lazyload({
    failure_limit : 10,
    effect: "fadeIn",
    skip_invisible : false
});
```

However, this just lazy loads everything at once instead of as the flexslider animates.

I was also able to get it to work on mouse over using this code:

```
 $("#flexcontainer img.lazy").lazyload({
     failure_limit : 10,
     effect: "fadeIn",
     event : "mouseover"
 });
```

However this doesn't work on touch devices.

I think the key is to create your own custom event and have it trigger after a flexslider callback such as the `after` callback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is what I did. I implemented my our lazy loading logic based on what lazy load library does on after event of flexslider that is triggered after the slide is done.

Comment: You lazy load solution doesn't make any sense for big image collections due to it loads ALL images. I proposed better solution below.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of offering an alternative solution - another option is to use a responsive slider which already has lazy load built into it, for example royal slider, here is the link -> http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/

Answer (score 1):

You might as well initialize lazyload with a custom trigger event ...

```
$jQ("img[data-original]").lazyload({
            effect: "fadeIn",
            skip_invisible: false,
            event: "forceLazyLoad"
        });
```

... and then call this event to preload all your images inside the flexslider with a call like:

```
$jQ('.flex-viewport').find('img[data-original]').trigger('forceLazyLoad');
```