# jquery horizontal image slider with lazyload

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I am currently building a horizontal grid image slider. I would like to lazy load images, so I would only like to show images that are currently only in the viewport.

I came accross http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload which works great for vertically sliding elements.

Has anyone come across something like this for horizontal sliding?

this is the function i am currently using with lazy load:

```
$(".lazy").each(function(i, val) {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-original"));
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

Can this be adapted to work horizontally?

Comment: Have you seen the horizontal examples?

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_wide.html
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_wide_container.html

Answer (score 0):

I use [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) to handle horizontal sliding ([example](http://www.icar.co.uk)). You can add lazy loading to it using the answer here: [Lazy Loading in Flexslider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360533/lazy-loading-in-flexslider)