# Lazy loading flexslider

Tags: javascript, loading, lazy-evaluation, flexslider

My Javascript skills are beginner at best but I've tried to implement the lazy loading flexslider solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20205074/3204532).
The slider and loading work well, however when the slider has cycled once I'm getting console errors:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeAttr' of undefined"

My JS is sitting in the head:

**JS**

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $(window).load(function() {
        $('.projcontainer').flexslider({
           slideshow: false,
           after: function(slider) {
              var slides = slider.slides,
                      index = slider.animatingTo,
                      $slide = $(slides[index]),
                      $img = $slide.find('img[data-src]');
              if ($img) {
                 $img.attr("src", $img.attr('data-src')).removeAttr("data-src");
              }
           }
        });
     });
  </script>
```

**Html:**

```
<li>
   <img class="lazy" src="loading.gif" data-src="myimage.png"/>
</li>
```

With limited knowledge I know that I need to complete the "else if" statement but it isn't happening for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `if ($img)` to `if ($img.length)`. Your if condition will always pass, since `$img` is never null (its a jQuery object).